# TypeScript intersection types with array reduce

Tags: typescript, types, reduce

I'm trying to get typings to work with a generic array reduce function which basically merges two objects. The following snippet is a dumped down version of the real code. Why is `fl`'s type `{}` and not `IFoo & IBar`?

*(I'm aware that this particular example can easily be replaced with a single `Object.assign()` call.)*

```
const flatten = <K, T>(prev: K, x: T): K & T => {
  return Object.assign(prev, x);
};

interface IFoo {
  foo: true;
}

interface IBar {
  bar: true;
}

const fooRes: IFoo = { foo: true };
const barRes: IBar = { bar: true };

const fl = [fooRes, barRes].reduce(flatten, {});

console.log(fl); // here, fl : {}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The signature of `reduce`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/584b314c4c56349983f9b8704f30c6cec2e6d37f/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1279) is

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U
```

(`T` is the type parameter of the array itself.) So, faced with the code

```
[fooRes, barRes].reduce(flatten, {})
```

the type checker's job is to figure out what `U` is. Let's walk through its reasoning:

1. `fooRes : IFoo` and `barRes : IBar`, so `[fooRes, barRes] : (IFoo | IBar)[]`
2. Thus, the array's `T ~ IFoo | IBar`
3. So `flatten` is being called with its `T` parameter set to `IFoo | IBar`
4. `flatten`'s return type (`K & T`) is therefore `K & (IFoo | IBar)`
5. Since `flatten`'s return type must be assignable to `U`, that gives us the constraint `U >= (U & (IFoo | IBar))`, which simplifies to `U >= (IFoo | IBar)`
6. The other bit of evidence is the `initialValue` parameter which has a type of `{}`
7. So `U >= {}`
8. The least upper bound of these two constraints is `{}`. So the type checker infers `U ~ {}`.

Why doesn't it realise that the return type is `IFoo & IBar`? The type checker doesn't reason about the runtime behaviour of your code - that `flatten`'s parameter takes on a variety of different types throughout the reduction. An array of type `(IFoo | IBar)[]` is not guaranteed to have both `IFoo`s and `IBar`s in it - it could just be an array of `IFoo`s. Deducing that `flatten`ing an heterogeneous list squashes its constitutent types down would require quite a sophisticated proof, and it doesn't seem reasonable to expect a machine to be able to write such a proof for you.

Comment: Awesome answer! Really appreciate the detailed explanation.